# Change a specific field in multiple object of a sub document mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am trying to change a specific field in multiple objects of a sub-document to false but I am having issues with mongoose when I try to use `$set` to update the document.

This is the data structure.

```
[{
    name: 'Joe',
    card: [
      { type: 'visa', select: true},
      { type: 'masterCard', select: false},
      { type: 'unionPay', select: true},
    ]
},{
    name: 'Pascal',
    card: [
      { type: 'unionPay', select: false},
      { type: 'visa', select: true},
      { type: 'masterCard', select: false},
    ]
}]
```

execpted result

```
[{
    name: 'Joe',
    card: [
      { type: 'visa', select: false}, <--- was changed to false
      { type: 'masterCard', select: false},
      { type: 'unionPay', select: false}, <--- was changed to false
    ]
},{
    name: 'Pascal',
    card: [
      { type: 'unionPay', select: false},
      { type: 'visa', select: true},
      { type: 'masterCard', select: false},
    ]
}]
```

I currently wrote this query but it is not working as expected.

```
 this.user.model().findOneAndUpdate(
 { name: 'Joe },
  {
    card:{$set: { select: false },
  },
 );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ScRx2XpZ9E

Use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

> The filtered positional operator $[] identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation

You can update 1 top-level index at one time

```
db.collection.update(
 { name: "Joe" },
 { $set: { "card.$[c].select": false } },
 { arrayFilters: [ { "c.type": "visa" } ] }
)
```

---

Use [db.collection.bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to make 2 queries in 1 go.

```
db.collection.bulkWrite( [
   {
      updateOne : {
         "filter":{ name: "Joe" },
         "update": { $set: { "card.$[c].select": false } },
         "arrayFilters": [ { "c.type": "visa" } ]
      }
   },
   {
      updateOne : {
         "filter":{ name: "Joe" },
         "update": { $set: { "card.$[c].select": false } },
         "arrayFilters": [ { "c.type": "unionPay" } ]
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. I used 
```
db.collection.update({
  name: "Joe"
},
{
  $set: {
    "card.$[c].select": false
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "c.select": {
        "$ne": false
      }
    }
  ]
})
```
and it worked without having to write bulk

Comment: @HenryOkonkwo Awesome :)